# want to use setvisibily method betwen two framelayout in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use two framelayouts to load the content. My problem is both pages are showing data at the same time. I want to use setVisibilty method in the main java file. When one frame is showing data the other frame hides automatically. Could anyone tell me the java codes. Here is the xml file:

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/content_frametwo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

I am giving you the java file here:-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

private void setFrameVisibility(boolean frameOneVisible){
    if (frameOneVisible){
        findViewById(R.id.content_frame).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.content_frametwo).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        findViewById(R.id.content_frame).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.content_frametwo).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.homepage) {
        Intent homepage = new Intent (MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(homepage);
                        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.foodpage) {
        //handle the food page here
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new FirstFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.schedulepage) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                , new ScheduleFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.emotionspage) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                , new EmotionsFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.basicneedspage) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frametwo
                , new BasicneedsFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.exit) {
        askBeforeExit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public void onBackPressed() {

    askBeforeExit();
}

private void askBeforeExit(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("Confirm Exit");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to quit?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Use ViewSwitcher. http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/11/example-of-viewswitcher.html

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function to set them both, but then you will have to make sure you always use that function:

```
private void setFrameVisibility(boolean frameOneVisible) {
    if (frameOneVisible) {
        findViewById(R.id.content_frame).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.content_frametwo).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        findViewById(R.id.content_frame).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.content_frametwo).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have pasted the same code in my main file. but still showing both the pages.

Comment: What kind of class is your 'main' file? And when are you calling this function?

Comment: You never call the function and please update your answer with the code, rather then adding an answer

Comment: See my comment above. You are never calling `setFrameVisibility()`, you only added it in your code

Comment: So what is the right way for this. sorry. i am new in android.

Comment: Simply call this function and supply a boolean on which one you want to see whenever it is necessary. I cannot decide that for you

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this by using this code:

inside onCreateView:

```
    frameLayout1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
    frameLayout2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout2);
```

When ever you want to change visibility:

```
    frameLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    frameLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Yes, inside your activity.